# Building a gcc cross compiler on linux, how do I know which "--target"s are supported and the exact keyword for specifying them?

Tags: gcc, cross-compilation, toolchain

I'm trying to build gcc compiler to producing executables that are supposed to run on x86-64 machines. I'm actually using existing 64bit gcc compiler on my computer. It is redundant but I'm doing it for learning purposes.

The problems is, I don't know how do I specify --target option. What should I type there? Would simply typing "x86-64" work?

What if I wanted the cross compiler to be producing executables for x86 machines and is supposed to be running on another x86-64  bit machine in order to compile the source code?, what keyword should I use for setting target and host?

I would like to know if there is any gcc manual specifying supported architectures for host and target machines and the right commands to specify them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an idea of the supported target architectures, you should look at [`configure`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=configure;hb=HEAD) and [`config.sub`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.sub;hb=HEAD) in whatever GCC sources you’re trying to build. You’ll also need matching binutils and a C library; [the GCC installation manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) provides details of the steps involved in configuring and building the compiler.

Beyond the architecture, you also need to decide which operating system and library to target; thus for Linux with the GNU C library on x86_64, you’d configure with `--target=x86_64-linux-gnu`. Shorter aliases exist, you can run `config.sub` to determine what they correspond to:

```
$ src/config.sub x86_64-linux
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

So `./configure --target=x86_64-linux` would be equivalent to `x86_64-linux-gnu`, which is equivalent to `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`.

Once configured and built, you’ll get a compiler which builds programs which can run on the configured target; the compiler itself will run on the configured host. Generally speaking you should only specify the target; it *is* possible to cross-build a cross-compiler (this is known as a [Canadian cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler#Canadian_Cross)), but if you’re just getting into cross-compilation you should leave that aside for now.